# Wake on Lan after wpeutil shutdown

Tags: wmi, shutdown, winpe

I've a little big problem with Winpe5.1. 
I have to WOL the computer after it was shuting down with wpeutil shutdown. 
The fact is that after the execution of this command, the network card is completly down and seems to have no power. 
I tried to force the power options from WMI but without succes. Does someone have an idea ?
Same result with shutdown.exe or psshutdown or PS Stop-Computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is Can't turn on by wake on lan after a long time turn off PC, if true, you should research about MAC Binding feature on router, modem, ..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but the problem isn't here. I can't WOL the computer even imediately after shutdwon with wpeutil shutdown command.